# Wordpress: Creating a custom table for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type defined in my Wordpress application, the data of which is stored inside `wp_postmeta` table in MySQL by default. However, since my custom post type has 16 form fields, it's not feasible to store each entry into `wp_postmeta`. I'm using the ACF plugin in Wordpress to create my custom post type.

So, is there a way to create a custom table in `PHPMyAdmin` for MySQL to store data coming from my custom post type?

Answer (score 2):

The ACF plugin is great, but the [PODS](http://pods.io/) Framework for Wordpress allows you to register custom post types and store the data in a custom table, all via the Wordpress Admin UI.